# pandas Remove rows with non-blank values per a field from a dataframe (Python 3.4/IPython)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new dataframe (ascombnoa) from an existing (ascomb) one where values of specific column (Discipline) are blank. I'm assuming that this is a string field as other values are words like "Math" and "Reading."

I tried this:

```
ascombnoa = ascomb[ascomb.Discipline] == ""
```

and it returned this:
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
ascombna = ascomb[pandas.isnull(ascomb['Discipline'])]
```

Comment: I think OP wants to create a new DataFrame whereas that 'Discipline' field **IS** empty.

Comment: I will not downvote but your answer is somehow wrong as **notnull** will only filter **NaN** whereas OP intentionally uses "", which isn't **NaN** and therefore will not be filtered. That said, I'm still await to OP response on what type 'Discipline' field really is.

Comment: I was operating under the assumption gained from the title of the question which states the OP wants to delete blank rows. If they are looking to fill `NaN` values with an empty string then `.fillna("")` should work. We'll see what clarification the OP gives.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, try this:

```
ascombnoa = ascomb[ascomb.Discipline == ""]
```

As updated by OP, the **blank** filed is actually **NaN**, you can make use of **isnull** method from pandas, like this:

```
ascombnoa = ascomb[pd.isnull(ascomb.Discipline)]
```

It would be the same as aus_lacy's answer from assumption :)

Comment: Thanks, Anzel! It runs now, but the result is a blank dataframe (headers only). To filter for empty cells, should I be using something other than ""?

Comment: @MichaelLance, can you show part of your data? it's hard to tell what's your meaning of blank, could it be **NaN**, space or etc.?

Comment: Is there an easy way to check the format of the field?

Comment: @MichaelLance, you can use `dtypes`, try: `df.dtypes`

Comment: @MichaelLance, or if you have that particular field index, you can simply do: `type(df['Discipline'][index_here]`

Comment: It's an object. I used ascombna = ascomb[pandas.isnull(ascomb['Discipline'])] and that worked.

Comment: @MichaelLance, does the **empty** field actually show anything? like **NaN**, or just blank?

Comment: @MichaelLance If you used my answer, then you should accept it for future SO users searching for a similar solution.

Comment: @MichaelLance, you should edit your question to state an update that you find out the blank fields are actually **NaN**.

Comment: @MichaelLance, I've updated my answer as well. And you can keep the accepted answer to aus_lacy, and Happy new year to both :)

Comment: Cool thanks. I don't have the rep points to upvote any answers, unfortunately. Happy New Year!